# How to check which users accept cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I want to check which users accept cookies so I can get a rough % of users that accept cookies on one of our PHP sites.

My idea is to create a temporary `acceptsCookies` column in the Users table to help keep track of this (e.g. if a user accepts cookies, then their `acceptsCookies` will be set to "Y", otherwise it will be set to "N").

How can I do this on a **single** page (setting a test cookie, checking if it was accepted/set, updating the DB) ?

Update:  To be clear, this has to be done 100% in PHP.

Comment: It doesn't sound very hard, JavaScript can set and read cookies as well. Try to do it yourself, and if you get stuck, come here for help with a more specific problem. This is a questions/answers site, not a build-my-code-for-me site.

Comment: @Truth:  I can't use Javascript, hence why I specified PHP and did not tag Javascript.

Comment: Then you should also specify in your question that you may not use JavaScript.

Comment: @Truth: Please stop responding, your general attitude and down-voting is not helpful at all.  It seems you are the only one who didn't understand the question as I already have two helpful answers, one of which is a very clever solution to what I was looking for.  Don't assume anything next time.

Comment: 2 Things, 1. I didn't downvote anything. Never accuse when you aren't sure. 2. This is a very highly rated site (SEO wise), and users searching **for the same issue as yours** might be confused about the answers because your question is only **similar** to theirs. I've been here for a while and the minimum standard for questions is here reasonable readability and understandability. And don't talk about my attitude, you're not paying me and I owe you nothing. My comments are there to help you and other users, not to humiliate or degrade you.

Comment: Your question is misleading due to implying the unrealizable requirement of doing it in a single request. Which has also been asked and answered before:  [Is it possible to check if user has cookies enabled in php without a page reload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655011/is-it-possible-to-check-if-user-has-cookies-enabled-in-php-without-a-page-reload)

Comment: @Truth: Actually, yes, you did downvote. You were the only "view" when you downvoted me to -1 and left your first comment above. Also, don't confuse others' misunderstanding with your own, especially when English isn't your first language. Lastly, writing "It doesn't sound very hard", " Try to do it yourself", and "not a build-my-code-for-me site" is completely unhelpful to me and any "other" person you might be trying to help. To prove you wrong, I already have my solution. So feel free to continue talking to yourself in order to help "others" as I've already found what I'm looking for.

Comment: In fact, no I haven't downvoted, and to prove it to you I'll really downvote it so you can witness. Also you must understand that you are not the first one that asks these kinds of questions, and if you want any help, you'll need to be very clear about what you need. What is a question not worthy to look at may prove otherwise with an addition of a single sentence. Like I said, no one here, especially me, is here to degrade you. But you shouldn't go on the offence and and attack people. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in a single step, as the cookie has to be SENT to the browser first, and will only sent back to you in a subsequent request. So if you had something like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_write_close(); // unlock session file so checkcookie.php below won't block.
    setcookie(...);
?>
<html>
<body>

<img src="checkcookie.php" width="0" height="0" />
```

you could have the checkcookie.php script update your session's acceptsCookie value.

Comment: Very clever, Marc, thank you.  So just to confirm, this would do it in a single page?

Comment: Yes, as the image triggers a separate request to the server. Personally I'd just do the check in a second page request, since using an asset for this purpose feels a bit 'iffy', even though it would work.

Comment: Technically two pages. One page sets the cookie, then when the browser requests that image script, your server will automatically get the cookie set by the main page, assuming the browser's allowing cookies.

Comment: @Marc B:  But as far as the user is concerned, just one "page", correct?

Comment: Yes. However, this just makes your server aware of the cookie capabilities a minute or two earlier. The cookie would STILL be sent on ANY request the user makes on your site, and those pages could do the update at that point too. Think of it as a restaurant that accepts reservations, but doesn't care if you make the reservation call on a cell phone while standing outside the front door.

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you can't do this on a single page. Another option would be to check in javascript then submit an ajax call to a different php page:

```
<script>
   var tmpcookie = new Date();
   chkcookie = (tmpcookie.getTime() + '');
   document.cookie = "chkcookie=" + chkcookie + "; path=/";
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(chkcookie,0) < 0) {
      //AJAX CALL IN HERE SAYING NO COOKIES
      }
    else {
      //AJAX CALL IN HERE SAYING ACCEPTING COOKIES
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you can't use javascript. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

PHP *alone* cannot determine if a user had accepted a cookie or not in a single page.

PHP sends the cookie as a header, and then reads the headers sent by the client **on the next page request**. PHP cannot find whether a cookie was accepted or not in the same page it was delivered. That's the realm of JavaScript.